# I have a complicated issue with firebase storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, upload, firebase-storage

I can't upload a simple image , what a silliness !

that's my code to upload image to firebase storage

```
storage.ref().child(imid).putString(this.state.img.base64 , 'base64')

imid = randomstring() + ".jpg";

this.state.img.base64 = base64string
```

- [check the base64 string](https://pastebin.com/Lq1fG7AZ)

it actually upload the image , but it does not upload it as image

even after downloading the uploaded file from firebase storage page

the OS can't realize and open it

[image]

Comment: The code included in this question doesn't make a lot of sense and really doesn't tell us what it does or why it's in the question; it appears the *imid* is defined after it's used. *To upload a file to Cloud Storage, you first create a reference to the full path of the file, including the file name.*  Why are you using *putString* instead of *ref.put(file)*. Where's the tailing closure? Have you gone through the [Getting Started Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files) and especially the code in the Upload from a Blob or File section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what is happening here is that you are converting the image into the base64 string and that is been saved as a file in the name of .jpg extension in the firebase storage. All this is success after downloading in the system you got the same file. But you got the file that you saved the base64 and not the image. Means the encoding of the file is not in the jpeg format rather it is in text file. Open the file using the notepad or any text editor, i hope you will see the base 64 string inside.

Only the file name is in JPEG and not the Image encoding

Yes the file extension is taken as jpeg but the file contains the base 64 string encoded as the plain text. So the OS is trying to open the file in the image opening tool causing the error.

Try uploading it as the file itself rather as base64 or else write the base 64 decoder in the firebase to convert and save.

Please go through this link for complete reference
https://github.com/CodeLinkIO/Firebase-Image-Upload-React-Native